# How to make sure files are present when usb mounts?

Tags: filesystems, mount, usb

When my computer mounts a USB, the files don't show up immediately, which is throwing off my script (which is quite quick). How do I make sure that the folder doesn't appear in my mounting directory (`/run/media/$HOME`) until all the files are at least listed?

Comment: @JacobVlijm The script is looking for files. It sees the directory the usb is mounted to, but not the files. I presume that this means that the system is creating the directory before mounting it.

Comment: @JacobVlijm How I am supposed to tell if the files are there? What if there just so happen to be 0 files? How can I tell the difference between 0 files and it not being mounted?

Comment: @JacobVlijm How about bash?

Answer (score 1):

To check if a directory is a mount point:
you can use `findmnt` to resolve a directory mount point back to the device it is on. Eg

```
$ findmnt -nul -o source /home
/dev/sda3
```

shows that my `/home` is mounted on partition 3.  If your directory exists but is not yet mounted findmnt will return nothing and exit with return code 1.

If you prefer, `df` on a directory will say which device the directory is on. Unlike findmnt you don't have to specify a mount point.  Eg

```
$ df /home/meuh
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3      102862592 48483876  49146872  50% /home
```

For a directory in `/run` not yet mounted you can expect something like

```
tmpfs            1966384  1296   1965088   1% /run
```